# Field type for foreign key field in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, mysql, yii, fieldtype

I'm porting my Yii 1.x application from `.sql` files-based database struture to [database migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration). I've noticed, that when using [`CDbMigration::addForeignKey`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration/#addForeignKey-detail) method, Yii uses `int(11) NOT NULL` as field type for all fields, that are foreign keys.

Is this correct? I've been taught for many years, that I should use `int(10) unsigned NOT NULL` type.

Comment: There would be no problem and that's Your choice.

Comment: What are you talking about? There isn't my choice at all. If I use `CDbMigration::addForeignKey`, it will force me to use `int(11) NOT NULL` and I can't do nothing about this.